# Had gathered and ample resources. Could had simultaneously be a modal verb and a possessive verb?

Tags: meaning-in-context, past-perfect

> - With the team he ***had*** gathered and ample resources, his success was guaranteed.
>
> Could ***had*** be a model verb with "gathered"( past perfect ) and a possessive verb with ample resources ( past simple )at the same time?

Comment: The more complete version would be "With the team he had gathered and *with* ample resources, his success was guaranteed. " *had gathered* is the only verb in that clause.

Comment: *Have* is never a **modal** verb. The term for its use in the perfect construction, as here, is **auxiliary**, and in other uses the term is **lexical**. In older English it may behave like an auxiliary even when its sense is lexical--for instance, *Have you any sugar?*--but this use is fairly rare now; it has largely disappeared from AmE.

Comment: @StoneyB It survives, but only in set phrases such as _"Have you no shame?"_ Or perhaps I should say "in _the_ set phrase", because no others come immediately to mind. (Cue a flood of such set phrases...)

Answer (score 2):

No, but your example sentence is perfect.

**Have** as an auxiliary verb forming a perfect tense and **have** meaning possession are two different senses of **have**. It's just like the way **can** means "able to" and "seal inside a can": it can only mean one of those at a time, at least in ordinary language. Using the same word simultaneously in two senses would be a pun, like “‘I’ll never put my arm in a tiger’s mouth again,’ said Tom **off-handedly**.”

Your sentence is perfect because the reader understands **with** as governing both **the team** and **ample resources**. Equivalently, you could have written:

> **With** the team he had gathered and **with** ample resources, his success was guaranteed.

Here's a sentence that can't be understood without using **have** in both senses—and consequently the sentence is nonsense:

> Eli **had** traveled 50 miles and a shovel.

A listener will find this sentence ungrammatical. Once **had** is heard to clearly make **travel** into the past perfect, a listener finds it too jarring for **had** to switch to its possessive sense and take **a shovel** as an object.

---

Now that you know all that, you might be curious to know that deliberate use of a single word to play two simultaneous grammatical roles is a figure of speech, known to rhetoricians as a [zeugma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_and_syllepsis). I've never seen it done with these two senses of **have**, but I think it must be possible.

Comment: _"He drove off in a huff and a Chevrolet."_

Comment: While I was here, I read the question and your answer (I always enjoy your answers).  Another very good one. +1 (don't understand why it hasn't attracted more)

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks for the kind words! I just commented on "You always dress in a black suit"—a difficult and subtle difference, which I'd never noticed before and I would have had a very hard time sorting out. :) That question seems to have lured some normally wise people into treating language as a formal system rather than a way of pointing. Unfortunately, when people tune out pointing, they usually don't see it when the missing element is pointed out to them.